# Find the work done by the force on a point moving on a curve

Tags: calculus, analysis, line-integrals

Question is: Calculate the mechanical work of the force  $$ \vec{F}=(y^2+z^2)\vec{i}+(x+y)\vec{k}$$

which acts on a point moving on the curve $$\gamma: \begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=4x\\ x^2+y^2=2x\\z≥0\end{cases}$$

Answer:

$$\gamma: \begin{cases}x(t)=2cos^2t\\ y(t)=2cost\cdot sint\\z(t)=2cost\end{cases}$$ where $$t \in [-\frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}]$$

then we have $$\gamma: \begin{cases}x'(t)=-2sin2t\\ y'(t)=2cos2t\\z'(t)=-2sint\end{cases}$$ where $$t \in [-\frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}]$$

Calculate the integral now: $$\int _{\gamma }\:\left(y^2+z^2\right)dx+\left(x+y\right)dz$$ =$$\int _{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi \:}{2}}\:\left[\left(\left(2costsint\right)^2+\left(2cost\right)^2\right)\left(-2sint\right)+\left(2cos^2t+2cost\cdot sint\right)\left(-2sint\right)\right]dt$$ = $$-\frac{8}{3}$$

Comment: When you say the teacher did not give examples of this kind of exercise, can you explain? Have you learnt line integral? Have you learnt Stokes' theorem? What is the part that is giving you difficulty? Please edit your question to provide additional context, your attempt and where you are stuck.

Comment: Parameterize the path and the computation is tedious but straightforward.

Comment: Yes, I solved line integrals of 1st kind and 2nd kind, but I am stuck here since I don't know how to draw the figure or how to parameterize the path here, since I don't know the z, I haven't learnt Stokes' theorem yet, I shouldn't have problems when it comes to solve the integral but I can't figure out how to parameterize the path and to find the domain in this problem.

Comment: Use $x = r \cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$ then $r = 2\cos\theta$ on the surface of the cylinder. $x = 2 \cos^2\theta, y = 2 \cos\theta \sin\theta$. To find $z$ at intersection with the sphere, plug in into the first equation and you get $z = \sqrt{2x} = 2\cos\theta$. So that is your parametrization. Note $ - \pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ for the line integral.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's all I wanted to know, I really appreciate! I will update once I solved it so other people can see it as well if it helps them, also hopefully you can check what I will have done by then and let me know if I managed to solve it correctly, thanks again!

Comment: $$\gamma: \begin{cases}x(t)=2cos^2t\\ y(t)=2cost\cdot sint\\z(t)=2cost\end{cases}$$ where $$t \in [-\frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}]$$

then we have $$\gamma: \begin{cases}x'(t)=-2sin2t\\ y'(t)=2cos2t\\z'(t)=-2sint\end{cases}$$ where $$t \in [-\frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}]$$

Calculate the integral now: $$\int _{\gamma }\:\left(y^2+z^2\right)dx+\left(x+y\right)dz$$ =$$\int _{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi \:}{2}}\:\left[\left(\left(2costsint\right)^2+\left(2cost\right)^2\right)\left(-2sint\right)+\left(2cos^2t+2cost\cdot sint\right)\left(-2sint\right)\right]dt$$ = $$-\frac{8}{3}$$ @MathLover

Comment: @tryingtosolvethispain good to see your effort. I will check it but can you please edit the question and add it there instead of in comments? That is how it is supposed to be. I know you are new to the site so letting you know.

Comment: I did, sorry I will keep it in mind for future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one mistake in your working though it does not change the answer, as that part of the integral is anyway zero. Please see error highlighted in red.

$\displaystyle \int _{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \left[(4 \sin^2 t \cos^2 t + 4 \cos^2 t) \left(\color {red} {-2 \sin t}  \right) + \left(2 \cos^2 t + 2 \sin t \cos t \right)\left(-2 \sin t\right)\right]dt$

It should instead be,

$\displaystyle \int _{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \left[(4 \sin^2 t \cos^2 t + 4 \cos^2 t) \left(\color {blue} {- 4 \sin t \cos t}  \right)+\left(2 \cos^2 t + 2 \sin t \cos t \right)\left(-2 \sin t\right)\right]dt$

As there is symmetry about xz plane and $\sin t$ and $\sin ^3 t$ are odd functions, the integral reduces to,

$\displaystyle \int _{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} - 4 \sin^2 t \cos t \ dt = - \frac{8}{3}$

Comment: Thanks for checking it! Would you mind explaining since I can't figure out where does -4sintcost come from?

Comment: $x'(t) = - 2 \sin 2t$, right?

Comment: Ah I am so stupid, sorry I didn't notice I typed it wrong and then I got really confused because I am quite tired, thanks a lot for your help today!

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: Also, is it possible you could show me how the figure looks like out of curiosity? I tried asking friends as well but they have no idea and I spent some time trying to figure out even using sites for this but I only seem to get the projection figure and I don't really understand. Is it not possible?

Comment: It is a cylinder of radius $1$ with center at $(1, 0, 0)$, intersected by a sphere of radius $2$ with center at $(2, 0, 0)$. Please note that the origin is on the surface of both the sphere and the cylinder. You may be able to visualize it in Geogebra 3D.

Comment: I used that site as well where I just put the equations I had, and it looks the same so it was alright, thanks again for helping me out!